# how to force a hover selector to not occur on a specific div

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I exclude the first element in a list from being targeted by a `:hover` selector?

**CSS:**

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > li :hover { 
  color:red !important;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<li>
@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Home", new { area = "" }, new 
{@class ="navbar-item" })
</li>
```

What I have tried so far:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-item")[0].onmouseover = function () {
  mouseOver()
};

function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-item")[0].style.color="blue !important"
}
```

Comment: actually i am looking to terminate hover operation

Comment: Just use the CSS `:not()` pseudo-class when you set up the initial selector and provide a selector to exclude in the parenthesis.

Comment: FYI: This line: `document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-item")[0].onmouseover = 
function () { mouseOver() };` is just terrible. Why find all the elements that match a class (and with a live node list to boot) just to throw out all but the first one?! Also, why supply an anonymous wrapper function to the `onmouseover` instead of just your actual function? Use this: `document.querySelector("navbar-item").onmouseover = mouseOver;`

Comment: You should also avoid all the `!important` designations as that makes it much harder to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Questions seeking help (**"why isn't/how to make this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and _the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself_. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: ^ We need to see the compiled HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use JavaScript/jQuery for this. Just use the ***`:nth-child`*** css selector like this:

```css
/* target all hovered li elements except the first one */
.navbar .navbar-nav > li:nth-child(n+2) a:hover { 
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

Or if you're not using the default bootstrap anchor links and just want to target the li element itself, just chain the `:nth-child` selector and the `:hover` selector like this:

```css
/* target all hovered li elements except the first one */
.navbar .navbar-nav > li:nth-child(n+2):hover { 
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li>
      Link 1
    </li>
    <li>
      Link 2
    </li>
    <li>
      Link 3
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `not()`.

```css
/* target all hovered li elements except the first one */
.navbar .navbar-nav > li:not(:first-child):hover { 
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li>
      Link 1
    </li>
    <li>
      Link 2
    </li>
    <li>
      Link 3
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```